# Delete object property doesn't work in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

Removing a object property using `delete` doesn't seem to work with angular.
The object remains unchanged.
The weird thing is that I can add properties to the object just fine.

Could it be because the object is exposed in `$scope` ? But how can I remove properties from it then?

This is my code

```
const {remote} = require('electron');

angular.module('myapp', []).service('db', function(){

  var data = remote.getGlobal('data');

  return {

    removeItem: function(item){
      console.log(delete data[item]); -> returns false!!
    }


  }

});
```

I'm calling the method from a controller:

```
$scope.removeAction = function(item){
  db.removeItem(item);
};
```

removeAction is called on ng-click of a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're just modifying `data` object in `db` service. I don't see any variable references directly bounded to your `$scope` variable. Hence you have to fetch data once again from the `db`(service) as you want to see the changes on `$scope` variable.

```
$scope.removeAction = function(item){
  //may be you have to update data variable once again
  //data = remote.getGlobal('data'); //then removeItem
  db.removeItem(item);
  //retrieve latest list from `db` service once again.
  $scope.data = db.getData(); //assumed data is collection retrieved from db.
};
```

Comment: but it doesn't remove it in the db service either. I console logged it just after delete and it stays the same, and delete returns false

Comment: Are you sure you `data` object is updated when you trying to delete item??

Comment: its not updated, thats what im trying to say. it doesnt delete the property

Comment: nvm i found out why, its because of the electron global thing. if I replace that with some example object it works..